Is there a way to add a function on errors in React Hook Form?
I'm looking into React and React Hook Form, I managed to display custom messages below the inputs but I also want to display an alert using react-toastify to let the user know about all the errors. How can I add a function a part from the existing error message?
I want to have something like errors && callMyFunction().

Why not useEffect(() => ..., [errors]) if you want to do something when the errors change?

Hello!
I tried this:
useEffect(() => errors && console.log("error"), [errors])
But for some reason, i still get the console.log on my first render but errors object should be empty on the first render (I think?) @jonrsharpe

"errors object should be empty on the first render" - what you're showing doesn't disprove that at all, an empty array is still truth-y.

oh okay that makes sense! how would I check if it's empty? I've tried errors.length but it gives undefined

something like: console.log(errors?.length) ?
I'm still getting undefined @HamedJimoh

errors?.length is undefined if errors is undefined, optional chaining doesn't magically create a value. Please do some debugging to see what you're actually dealing with.

That's why i'm asking how to handle this situation. Console.logging error gives me the errors i'm trying to get but errors?.length still is at undefined.

Like i said, on the first render it gives undefined and i'm not sure how to check if anything's inside before i do anything else.
i'm both new to React and React Hook Forms so i'm not sure how to proceed.

The function handleSubmit receives two parameters:

onValid for handling successful submissions.
onInvalid for handling errors.

onInvalid is triggered whenever the form is submitted with errors.
Here's an example:
const onError = (fieldsErrors) => {
  for (const fieldName in fieldsErrors) {
    toast.error(`Error in ${fieldName}: ${fieldsErrors[fieldName].message}`);
  }
};

Then, in your form:
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
);


quick question, this works great (thank you very much for the functional example of my own problem)! I just want to clarify, why is the $needed here?

You're welcome! The $ is a Template literals

I went through the React Hook Form docs and I realised the errors property of the formState returns an object and not an array (https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/formstate). Therefore, If you want to trigger a toast whenever there is an error, then you can just achieve this with the useEffect hook using this reproducible code I have written:
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const ContactPage = () => {
  const { formState: { errors }, } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    },
    mode: "all",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const errorMessages = Object.values(errors);

    if (errorMessages.length > 0) {
      for (const error of errorMessages) {
        toast.error(error.message, {
          position: "top-center",
          hideProgressBar: true,
          toastId: error.message, //This prevents the toast from opening the same error message multiple times whenever errors change
        });
      }
    }
  }, [Object.values(errors).length]);
}


I hope this solves it for you.

[Object.values(errors).length] does not prompt a change when there is a change in what errors there are, and the number of errors remains the same

It does really prompt a change and runs the useEffect() whenever the length of the errors changes. I had this minimal code tested.

That's not the problem. Consider what happens when you go from { "error1": "some error" } to { "error2": "other error" }

That is not the way the React Hook Form's formState errors is structured. The errors is structured (based on the sample code) as { errors: { "firstName": { message: "FirstName is required" } }, {"lastName": {message: "LastName is required" } } }. So this means, the errorsstatelength``` would continue to grow relative to the individual field errors.

No, if you change from { errors: { "firstName": { message: "FirstName is required" } } } to { errors: { "firstName": { message: "Invalid FirstName" } } } or similar

You're right. I think I get your point now. That was a good catch. Thank you.
